# Variable inside shell script in Jenkins groovy script not storing value

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am currently in the process of configuring a Jenkins pipeline using a Groovy script.

Inside the Groovy script, in one of the stages, I am executing a Shell script as follows:

```
pipeline {
parameters {
   
}

agent {
    docker {
    
    }
}

stages {
    stage('abc') {
        steps {
            script {
                sh '''#!/bin/bash -x
                currentYear = `date +"%Y"`
                echo ${currentYear}
                '''
            }
        }
        
    }
}
}
```

The date calculation is working fine. However the echo command is not displaying anything. And any further usage of this variable yields a blank.

Can anyone please help me in understanding why this variable doesn't have any value?

Comment: Remove spaces around `=` sign. Replace old syntax `\`date +"%Y"\`` by `$(date +"%Y")`

Comment: Didn't you get an error message about `currentYear: command not found`?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
  script{

    result=sh(script:'''
    currentYear = `date +"%Y"`
    echo $currentYear

     ''',returnStdout:true).trim()
   }
```

or try this in your code:

```
       script {
            sh '''#!/bin/bash -x
            currentYear = `date +"%Y"`
            echo $currentYear
            '''
        }
```